# Black window flashes then disappears when I start Blender 2.72

Tags: installation

I've been looking for a solution to my problem for a few days without finding it, so I'm posting my question here hoping I'm in the right place.

I had Blender 2.68 working very well, and I wanted to switch to version 2.72. Because I have Windows Vista 32-bit, I downloaded the 32-bit .exe file, which installed without problems, but when I try to open Blender, a small black window opens and quickly closes and then nothing.

I don't know what might be causing this, your help would be welcome. Thanks in advance!

Cordially, Fred

Comment: Try to find help here, they might understand you (and you them): http://blenderclan.tuxfamily.org/html/modules/newbb/

Comment: @Fred27 try using the installer not the zip version

Comment: maybe related?  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16500/blender-2-72-blender-app-exe

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2203/599

Comment: What happens if you download the zip version instead of the installer? To run it all you need to do is extract it somewhere and run the blender.exe file contained in the resulting directory.

Comment: It sounds like the blender Python console is opening, and encountering an error and crashing. Have you tried the classic uninstall/reinstall? Also, maybe try uninstalling 2.68 before opening 2.72 again.

Comment: Try running Blender from a command line; maybe then you'll be able to see an error of sorts.